# Cannot build any functions with cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Somehow I keep getting build failures in our new cloud environment. I tried with nodejs and python default HelloWorld cloud functions, both failed with no specific error messages. Below is one of the ERRORs:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed: {"error":{"buildpackId":"","buildpackVersion":"","errorType":"OK","canonicalCode":"OK","errorId":"","errorMessage":""},"stats":[{"buildpackId":"google.utils.archive-source","buildpackVersion":"0.0.1","totalDurationMs":45,"userDurationMs":41},{"buildpackId":"google.python.functions-framework","buildpackVersion":"0.9.5","totalDurationMs":78,"userDurationMs":78},{"buildpackId":"google.python.pip","buildpackVersion":"0.9.2","totalDurationMs":5190,"userDurationMs":5186},{"buildpackId":"google.utils.label","buildpackVersion":"0.0.1","totalDurationMs":0,"userDurationMs":0}],"warnings":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did have the same problem. Even the examples did not work (tried python and nodejs, as well as the Terraform module examples).

As I drilled down, I found some build logs in Cloud Build History:

```
"build": eu.gcr.io/<project-id>/gcf/<region>/<some-uuid>:hello_gcs_version-2 - GET https://eu.gcr.io/v2/token?scope=repository%3A<project-id>%2Fgcf%2F<region>%2F<same-uuid>%3Apush%2Cpull&scope=repository%3Afn-img%2Fbuildpacks%2Fpython39%2Frun%3Apull&service=eu.gcr.io: DENIED: Token exchange failed for project '<project-id>'. Org Policy Violated: 'eu' violates constraint 'constraints/gcp.resourceLocations'
```

For me what it took was to override the Organization Policy (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/orgpolicies/gcp-resourceLocations/edit-v2) and
make it ["Google Managed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juItZ.png)